# Android Game - set time limit to 30 seconds

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm working on a simple Android game.

When you press play, a timer counts down from 30, and once the timer hits zero, I want to call the function goToGameOver(). I can't seem to get a Handler working properly so I tried out the standard Timer class and it's not even close to real-time.

Also, as the timer counts down, I'd like to pass the time remaining into a global variable x every second, so that I can paint it onto the screen in a separate method.

Any thoughts on how I can best approach this? Thanks!

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) { 
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
   x = millisUntilFinished / 1000; 
} 
public void onFinish() {
 goToGameOver(); 
} }.start();
```

EDIT:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

import com.name.framework.Game;
import com.name.framework.Graphics;
import com.name.framework.Image;
import com.name.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.name.framework.Screen;

// Creates live game screen
public class GameScreen extends Screen {
enum GameState {
    Running, Paused, GameOver
}

GameState state = GameState.Running;

// Instance variables
Random r = new Random();
int z = r.nextInt(16);
private int score = 0;


int count = 0;
private Runnable run;

public GameScreen(Game game) {
    super(game);

    Assets.paint = new Paint();
    Assets.paint.setTextSize(30);
    Assets.paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    Assets.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Assets.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);



}

// Check if touch coordinates fall in certain range
    private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y && event.y < y + height - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

@Override
public void update(float deltaTime) {
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

    // Call appropriate update method based on game state
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        updatePaused(touchEvents);
    if (state == GameState.GameOver)
        updateGameOver(touchEvents);
}

// Responds to in-game interaction
private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {


    final Handler hand = new Handler();
    run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == 30) { //will end if count reach 30 which means 30 second
                goToMenu(); 
            } 
            else
            {
                count += 1; //add 1 every second
                hand.postDelayed(run, 1000); //will call the runnable after 1 second

            }
        }
    };
    hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);

    int len = touchEvents.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = (TouchEvent) touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {



            switch(z) {

            // Blue is correct
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                if (inBounds(event, 125, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                    score += 1;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 125, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                break;

            // Green is correct
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
                if (inBounds(event, 125, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                    score += 1;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 125, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                break;

            // Red is correct
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
            case 11:
                if (inBounds(event, 125, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 125, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                    score += 1;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                break;

            // Yellow is correct
            case 12:
            case 13:
            case 14:
            case 15:
                if (inBounds(event, 125, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 150, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 125, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.bad.play(0.8f);
                    score -= 5;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                else if (inBounds(event, 425, 300, 250, 100)) {
                    Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                    score += 1;
                    z = r.nextInt(16); }
                break;  
            }

            // Pause button
            if (inBounds(event, 750, 0, 50, 50)) {
                Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                Assets.theme.pause();
                state = GameState.Paused;
            }
        }

        // Prevents score from becoming negative
        if (score < 0) {
            score = 0;
        }
    }
}

// Responds to pause menu interaction
private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
    int len = touchEvents.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
        if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

            // Resume button
            if (inBounds(event, 125, 150, 250, 100)) {
                Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                Assets.theme.play();
                state = GameState.Running; }

            // Restart button
            else if (inBounds(event, 425, 150, 250, 100)) {
                Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                Assets.theme.play();
                nullify();
                state = GameState.Running; }

            // Mute button
            else if (inBounds(event, 125, 300, 250, 100)) {
                Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                }

            // Menu button
            else if (inBounds(event, 425, 300, 250, 100)) {
                Assets.pop.play(0.8f);
                //Assets.theme.seekBegin(); // not sure if I should do this
                Assets.theme.play();
                nullify();
                goToMenu(); }

            }
        }
    }

// Responds to game over interaction
private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

}

@Override
public void paint(float deltaTime) {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.clearScreen(16777215);
    g.drawImage(Assets.score, 20, 430);
    g.drawImage(Assets.blue, 125, 150);
    g.drawImage(Assets.green, 425, 150);
    g.drawImage(Assets.red, 125, 300);
    g.drawImage(Assets.yellow, 425, 300);
    g.drawString(""+ score, 135, 465, Assets.paint);
    //g.drawString(""+x, 750, 430, Assets.paint);

    // Adds text to array and draws random one
    ArrayList<Image> colors = new ArrayList<Image>();
    colors.add(Assets.blueInBlue);
    colors.add(Assets.blueInGreen);
    colors.add(Assets.blueInRed);
    colors.add(Assets.blueInYellow);
    colors.add(Assets.greenInBlue);
    colors.add(Assets.greenInGreen);
    colors.add(Assets.greenInRed);
    colors.add(Assets.greenInYellow);
    colors.add(Assets.redInBlue);
    colors.add(Assets.redInGreen);
    colors.add(Assets.redInRed);
    colors.add(Assets.redInYellow);
    colors.add(Assets.yellowInBlue);
    colors.add(Assets.yellowInGreen);
    colors.add(Assets.yellowInRed);
    colors.add(Assets.yellowInYellow);

    if (state == GameState.Running) {
        g.drawImage(colors.get(z), 0, 0);
    }

    // Calls the appropriate function to draw the UI based on game state
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        drawRunningUI();
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        drawPausedUI();
    if (state == GameState.GameOver)
        drawGameOverUI();
}

// Draws in-game UI
private void drawRunningUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(Assets.pause, 750, 0);
}

// Draws pause menu UI
private void drawPausedUI() {
    Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
    g.drawImage(Assets.paused, 0, 0);
    g.drawImage(Assets.resume, 125, 150);
    g.drawImage(Assets.restart, 425, 150);
    g.drawImage(Assets.mute, 125, 300);
    g.drawImage(Assets.returnToMenu, 425, 300);
}

// Draws game over UI
private void drawGameOverUI() {

}

// Pause function
@Override
public void pause() {
    if (state == GameState.Running)
        state = GameState.Paused;
}

// Resume function
@Override
public void resume() {
    if (state == GameState.Paused)
        state = GameState.Running;
}

@Override
public void backButton() {
    pause();
}

private void goToGameOver() {
    game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));

}

// Resets timer and score
private void nullify() {
    score = 0;

    // Calls garbage collector to clean up memory
    System.gc();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: post the code where you used the handler.. or post some code you have

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Sorry for the formatting. Stuck on mobile at the moment.

Comment: new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         x = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         goToGameOver();
     }
  }.start();

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thanks for the edit, will be back on PC soon

Comment: @user2901181 In your question you say that you "use the standard `Timer` class". However, in the code snippet you are using the `CountDownTimer` class, which is very different. I recommend clarifying your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `handler` for this even though you said that you've tried it, but i think you did not implement it correctly.

Here is the implementation and it work great on mine.

```
final Handler hand = new Handler();
    run = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(count == 30) { //will end if count reach 30 which means 30 second
                goToGameOver(); 
            } 
            else
            {
                count += 1; //add 1 every second
                hand.postDelayed(run, 1000); //will call the runnable after 1 second

            }
        }
    };
    hand.postDelayed(run, 1000);
```

Make sure that `count` and `handler` are `global fields`.

Comment: Thanks very much, please see my edit if you don't mind helping me through this one last issue.

Comment: @user2901181 remove looper.prepare

Comment: Then the error reads `"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"`.

Comment: @user2901181 can you post the whole class that implement that handler

Comment: @user2901181 it is not a class, it is a method please post the entire class

Comment: @user2901181 are you using activity as a base class of your Screen??

Comment: No, I'm not. I built most of this based on a tutorial and I believe they stated that the entire game would be built in a single activity. Does that sound wrong..?

Comment: @user2901181 yes it does, because you cant call a handler with out a reference to an activity

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm pretty far into this project and just using my Screen class to create different segments of the game. Is it easy to implement an Activity at this point? Or is there a workaround I can use instead of a Handler?

Comment: @user2901181 it depends how complicated your current design of class is. and also activity is not that hard to master. Maybe some java countdown timer,